# Azure BLOB Storage REST API Uploading a file throws 403 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, http-status-code-403, azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I am trying to upload a PDF to a Azure Blob Storage Container using **Share Access Key** (SAS).
Code was working fine, but suddenly it started throwing the **403 - Forbidden Exception**.

Response Status Message:

*Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.*

As mentioned in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting#the-client-is-receiving-403-messages), one of the possible causes for 403 could be expired a shared access key, hence I refreshed the key and tried with the new one, still no luck.

I am invoking the `UploadBlobToStorageContainer` method for a Console Application (.NET Framework 4.6.2)

CODE:

```
    public string AzureStorageAccountName { get; set; }

    public string AzureStorageAccessKey { get; set; }

    public string X_MS_VERSION
    {
        get
        {
            return "2017-04-17";
        }
    }

    public string X_MS_CLIENT_REQUEST_ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _x_ms_client_request_id;
        }
    }

    public string BaseURI
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/", AzureStorageAccountName);
        }
    }

    private bool UploadBlobToStorageContainer(string filePath, string targetFolderPath, string containerName)
    {
        bool isUploaded = false;
        try
        {                
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
            long contentLength = fileInfo.Length;
            long range = contentLength - 1;
            string method = "PUT";
            string contentType = "application/pdf";
            string blobName = fileInfo.Name;
            string blobType = "BlockBlob";
            string dateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string blobURI = BaseURI + containerName + "/" + blobName;
            string xmsHeader = $"x-ms-blob-type:{blobType}\nx-ms-date:{dateString}\nx-ms-version:{X_MS_VERSION}";
            string resHeader = $"/{AzureStorageAccountName}/{containerName}/{blobName}";

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetFolderPath))
            {
                blobName = targetFolderPath + "/" + fileInfo.Name;
            }
            
            if (WebRequest.Create(blobURI) is HttpWebRequest request)
            {
                request.Method = method;
                request.ContentLength = contentLength;
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", blobType);
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateString);
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", X_MS_VERSION);                    
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetAuthorizationHeader(method, xmsHeader, resHeader, contentType, contentLength));

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    byte[] fileContents = null;
                    using (FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                    {
                        fileContents = new byte[fs.Length];
                        fs.Read(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                }

                if (request.GetResponse() is HttpWebResponse response)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                    {
                        isUploaded = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isUploaded = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is WebException wex)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (wex.Response is HttpWebResponse exr)
                {
                    sb.Append("StatusCode: " + exr.StatusCode + " - ");
                    sb.Append("Description: " + exr.StatusDescription + " - ");
                }
                sb.Append("ErrorStatus: " + wex.Status);
                Log.LogMessage(LogLevel.ERROR, "AzureBlobApi: UploadBlobToContainer: File upload failed. Reason: " + sb.ToString());
            }
            Log.LogException(ex);
        }
        return isUploaded;
    }

    private string GetAuthorizationHeader(string method, string xmsHeader, string resHeader, string contentType, long contentLength)
    {
        //Do NOT REMOVE THE \n. It is a request header placeholder
        /*
            GET\n //HTTP Verb
            \n    //Content-Encoding
            \n    //Content-Language
            \n    //Content-Length (empty string when zero)
            \n    //Content-MD5
            \n    //Content-Type
            \n    //Date
            \n    //If-Modified-Since 
            \n    //If-Match
            \n    //If-None-Match
            \n    //If-Unmodified-Since
            \n    //Range
            x-ms-date:Fri, 26 Jun 2015 23:39:12 GMT
            x-ms-version:2015-02-21 //CanonicalizedHeaders
            /myaccount/mycontainer\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container\ntimeout: 20    //CanonicalizedResource
        */
        
        string strToSign = $"{method}\n\n\n\n{contentLength}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{xmsHeader}\n{resHeader}";

        string signatureString = GetHashedString(strToSign, AzureStorageAccessKey);

        string authorizationHeader = string.Format(
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
             "{0} {1}:{2}",
             "SharedKey",
             AzureStorageAccountName,
             signatureString);

        return authorizationHeader;
    }

    private string GetHashedString(string signingString, string accessKey)
    {
        string encString = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(accessKey);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
            {
                byte[] dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingString);
                encString = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.LogMessage(LogLevel.ERROR, $"AzureBlobApi: GetHashedString: Exception getting hash string {ex.Message}");
        }
        return encString;
    }
```

**Headers**

```
PUT



518262







x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Sun, 30 Aug 2020 08:43:31 GMT
x-ms-version:2017-04-17
/mystorage/documentcontainer/cricket/test document.pdf
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Raghunathan S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my problem. When i ran the request through POSTMAN, figured out that then resource uri in the header is URLEncoded, which i didn't do in my code and the name of the file that i am trying to upload as a space in-between "test document.pdf"

Response from PostMan

```
'PUT


518262

application/pdf






x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Mon, 31 Aug 2020 04:41:25 GMT
x-ms-version:2019-12-12
/mystorage/documentcontainer/cricket/test%20document.pdf'
```

whereas the header generated for signing from my code is

```
PUT



518262







x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Sun, 30 Aug 2020 08:43:31 GMT
x-ms-version:2017-04-17
/mystorage/documentcontainer/cricket/test document.pdf
```

When i made the following change in my code, by URL encoding the file name

```
string blobName = Uri.EscapeUriString(fileInfo.Name);
```

it worked and the files got uploaded successfully.

Thanks Guys for the Help.

Answer (score 0):

Http 403 is usually caused by authentication failure, please ensure the SAS has enough permission to create and write blob in the specified container, and also ensure that the container itself already exists(as it needs additional permission to create container), for more details about SAS permissions please refer to [Create a service SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Constructing-a-Service-SAS?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [Create an account SAS.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-an-account-sas)

An easy way to validate if SAS has enough permissions is to  call Azure storage client library's `blockBlob.UploadFromFile()` in your code, and see if it works or same error is reported there as well.

To use container SAS in DMLib:

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name/testaaa?st=2020-02-15T08%3A30%3A00Z&se=2020-02-20T08%3A30%3A00Z&sp=rwdl&sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=<Replaced>"));
TransferManager.UploadAsync(@"c:\Test.pdf", blob).Wait();
```

Comment: @HarishitaSingh-MSFT - SAS has all the required permissions and container also exists. I am not trying to create a container, but uploading a file. Moreover the above code that i posted was working fine and all of a sudden started getting the 403. I tried refreshing the shared key and no luck still.  I cannot use the Azure Storage SDK as it required .NET 4.7.2 My Project has to run under 4.6.1 only.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code.

1.in the `GetAuthorizationHeader()` method, please use the following line of code instead of yours:

```
string strToSign = $"{method}\n\n\n{contentLength}\n\n{contentType}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{xmsHeader}\n{resHeader}";
```

2.in the `UploadBlobToStorageContainer()` method, please add contentType to the request, like below:

```
                request.Method = method;

                //add contentType here
                request.ContentType = contentType;
                request.ContentLength = contentLength;
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", blobType);
```

3.For X_MS_VERSION, I suggest that you can use the latest version 2019-12-12, like below:

```
    public string X_MS_VERSION
    {
        get
        {
            return "2019-12-12";
        }
    }
```

At last, I posted the working code sample. If you still have problems, please try the code below(Note that I assume the targetFolderPath is empty in the sample, if you want to upload file to a directory, please adjust the code according):

```
    //other code

    public string X_MS_VERSION
    {
        get
        {
            return "2019-12-12";
        }
    }



    private bool UploadBlobToStorageContainer(string filePath, string targetFolderPath, string containerName)
    {
        bool isUploaded = false;
        try
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
            long contentLength = fileInfo.Length;
            long range = contentLength;
            string method = "PUT";
            string contentType = "application/pdf";
            string blobName = fileInfo.Name;
            string blobType = "BlockBlob";
            string dateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string blobURI = BaseURI + containerName + "/" + blobName;
            string xmsHeader = $"x-ms-blob-type:{blobType}\nx-ms-date:{dateString}\nx-ms-version:{X_MS_VERSION}";
            string resHeader = $"/{AzureStorageAccountName}/{containerName}/{blobName}";

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetFolderPath))
            {
                blobName = targetFolderPath + "/" + fileInfo.Name;
            }

            if (WebRequest.Create(blobURI) is HttpWebRequest request)
            {
                request.Method = method;
                request.ContentType = contentType;
                request.ContentLength = contentLength;
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", blobType);
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateString);
                request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", X_MS_VERSION);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetAuthorizationHeader(method, xmsHeader, resHeader, contentType, contentLength));

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    byte[] fileContents = null;
                    using (FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                    {
                        fileContents = new byte[fs.Length];
                        fs.Read(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                }

                if (request.GetResponse() is HttpWebResponse response)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                    {
                        isUploaded = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isUploaded = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is WebException wex)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (wex.Response is HttpWebResponse exr)
                {
                    sb.Append("StatusCode: " + exr.StatusCode + " - ");
                    sb.Append("Description: " + exr.StatusDescription + " - ");
                }
                sb.Append("ErrorStatus: " + wex.Status);
                Log.LogMessage(LogLevel.ERROR, "AzureBlobApi: UploadBlobToContainer: File upload failed. Reason: " + sb.ToString());
            }
            Log.LogException(ex);
        }
        return isUploaded;
    }




   private string GetAuthorizationHeader(string method, string xmsHeader, string resHeader, string contentType, long contentLength)
    {
        //Do NOT REMOVE THE \n. It is a request header placeholder
        /*
            GET\n //HTTP Verb
            \n    //Content-Encoding
            \n    //Content-Language
            \n    //Content-Length (empty string when zero)
            \n    //Content-MD5
            \n    //Content-Type
            \n    //Date
            \n    //If-Modified-Since 
            \n    //If-Match
            \n    //If-None-Match
            \n    //If-Unmodified-Since
            \n    //Range
            x-ms-date:Fri, 26 Jun 2015 23:39:12 GMT
            x-ms-version:2015-02-21 //CanonicalizedHeaders
            /myaccount/mycontainer\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container\ntimeout: 20    //CanonicalizedResource
        */

        string strToSign = $"{method}\n\n\n{contentLength}\n\n{contentType}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{xmsHeader}\n{resHeader}";

        string signatureString = GetHashedString(strToSign, AzureStorageAccessKey);

        string authorizationHeader = string.Format(
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
             "{0} {1}:{2}",
             "SharedKey",
             AzureStorageAccountName,
             signatureString);

        return authorizationHeader;
    }



   //other code
```

Comment: I tried your code, still no luck, getting the same 403-Forbidden error. not sure what i am missing here.

Comment: @RaghunathanSundarrajan, can you please update you post with the lasted code you're using? I tested my code, everything is ok.